# What's the deal with [Excel], [VBA] and [Excel-VBA] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Example question: [What event happens when I select a sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19472014/1306322)

I often see them in different combinations in new users' questions, probably not giving it a lot of thought.

But does each one of these three tags need to exist separately?

FYI **19,184** questions have [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) tag and **11,113** questions have [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag.

[vba](/questions/tagged/vba) wiki excertp:

> Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) is an event-driven, object-oriented programming language for writing macros, used for the entire Office suite. If your question is specifically about programming Excel, Access, Word or Outlook, use the appropriate tag: excel-vba, access-vba, word-vba or ...

[excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) wiki excerpt

> VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) is the dominant programming language for Microsoft Office Applications [Word, Excel, Access...].

IMO [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) should be merged with [vba](/questions/tagged/vba). But please share your opinion on the matter instead of just leaving me wondering why exactly this is a bad idea.

Comment: The community has a dislike for "stacking" tags (combining two tags for a single meaning, as in `excel` `vba`).  I'm guessing that `excel-vba` probably exists so that it can be followed.

Comment: I'm also familiar with the fact that if you enter a tag name of a synonimized tag, although you can't see such a tag, the first suggested one is usually the one it's merged with, and from the description you can 1) find the right tag and 2) find out new things about the area you're having problems with in.

Comment: You also have access-vba, word-vba, etc. If used properly, they will be attached to questions that use specific object-models for each of the applications. So in addition to what @RobertHarvey mentioned about the ability to follow only one of the applications, if you are following more, the distinction is particularly convenient in those cases where the objects are similarly named.

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but isn't it better to use generic tag combinations, like `access, vba` or `word, vba` instead of rarely found and thus used tags? Even if the user isn't new to the site, they may not be aware that such a specific tag even exists. Some words are contained in so many tags that the one you might be looking for may not show up in the suggested tags box (it only shows 6 most used tags).

Comment: It depends on the tags themselves - it's usually a case by case thing.  For me, this seems alright to place in a combination, however some may argue that an `excel-vba` tag is meant for Excel-specific VBA built-in functionality/capabilities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) refers to VBA when specifically applied to Excel.  [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) is more generic and specifically reference to VBA in any application (Outlook, Word, Access)

[excel](/questions/tagged/excel) is a different tag is while it could refer to Excel and VBA, it could also refer to Excel on its own.  While asking about specific formulas in excel, there are some questions that have been accepted in the past, although generally they are more accepted on Super User.

In the end, all 3 tags reference slight different things and may not necessarily be the same thing.

Ultimately, [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) is a separate tag for historical reasons.  Is it closely related to [vba](/questions/tagged/vba)?  Absolutely, but it the Excel implementation happens to be one of the most common and is very wildly used in business on a regular basis.  I hate using VBA in Excel (if I am going to use a Microsoft developed language, give me a .Net language any day of the week and 45 times on Monday), but because the IDE is so widely available, I program with it daily.  And because there is so many specific functions and methods for Excel, VBA in Excel happens to common and probably deserves its own tag